# Gracenote Android - How to retrieve Artist Biography and Album Review?

Tags: android, sdk, gracenote

On the Developers Guide, it was said that the app must be entitled to retrieve Artist Biography and Album Review data. However, I don't find any way to register my app to be able to retrieve that information.

I have set the GN Properties like the Guide said:

```
content.contributor.biography = true
content.review = true
```

But the SDK still returns `null`.

Anybody know any idea how to resolve this? How to register the app for Biography & Review data permissions? Or maybe there's another alternative APIs to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

The entitlements are handled on the server side, not in your app. If you got a Client ID from the developer site (developer.gracenote.com) it should be entitled to retrieve Biography and Album Review.

It's possible that the particular artist/album you are looking up does not have a Biography or Review. Does this happen for all queries, or just some?

Lastly, you could try using the Web API (https://developer.gracenote.com/web-api) just to double check.

Comment: It happens to all queries. Yes, I know that it has to be entitled from the Gracenote server, But I don't find any way to make my Client ID entitled for those informations. For now, I use an alternative where I get the biography and album review URL, then I fetch the URL to my app. However, it's really not efficient to do a double work like that.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion by hsingh?

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile client implementation guide is wrong. Please set:

content.contributor.biography = "1"
content.review = "1"

and not equal to true. Please look at the "GNConfig" class in the "docs/android_mobile_client_api/start_here.html" for more 
details on the syntax.

Comment: nope, I have already set it using "1" or "0" from the beginning. Nothing works.